# Source branch behind target branch by n commits

Tags: git, github, git-merge

In my project the `master` branch contains the released state and the `development`  branch is where the development is done.

The project was initially imported from SVN into the master branch and then development branch was created. The project was worked on using the development branch.

After a while, I wanted to merge development with master but got a conflict. (I think I may have inadvertantly added a `CHANGELOG` file to the master branch) Github displayed a message like `The source branch is 1 commits behind the target branch`. Anyway, I decided to merge the master back into the development branch and that *seemed* to fix the problem. I was able to merge the development branch with the master.

A short while later I wanted to merge development to master a second time and got a similar message `The source branch is 2 commits behind the target branch`. This seems to indicate that my previous action did not solve the problem.

Why is my development branch behind the master branch? What do I have to do to 
get them back in sync?

The graph looks like this
[image]

I'm obviously doing something wrong here but I don't understand what it could be.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What the message means? How you should handle merges? Also, did you want to merge development *to* master or master *to* development?

Comment: @kowsky edited question. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph looks odd: In the line `Merge branch 'development' into 'master'`, the purple branch was mergen into master. But the red branch is the one marked as `development`. It looks like some other development branch was merged into master.

The message `The source branch is 2 commits behind the target branch` means there are two commits reachable from the target (`master`) branch but not from the source branch (`development`). I would guess these are the `First prod release` and `Merge branch 'development' into 'master'` commits, but we would need to see more of your repositories history to know for sure.

Comment: the problem does seem to have been the 'purple' branch. I can't figure out exactly where it came from. In the end I did a local merge which was a bit messy but fortunately not too much work

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to merge master branch to development branch.

If you want to keep your development branch updated with master branch, you should use `git rebase`.

```
      A---B---C development
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

After you run either of the following commands:

```
git rebase master
git rebase master development
```

your commit history would be:

```
              A'--B'--C' development
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

Comment: Hmmm... this isn't even related to the question, but, according to the most popular branching strategy, you certainly can (and perhaps should) merge master into develop after each release. And, you never would be able to rebase develop...

Comment: This seems to be the "official" way to resolve this issue, but could you add some more detail?  Do I have to have the branch "development" checked out prior to the rebase?  Should I have "master" checked out?  Does it matter?  What implications does this have on losing any changes to "development"?  And then how do I merge C' back into "master"?  Just normal?

Comment: `git rebase --help` has some good explanations and examples.